# A survey on locally finite groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

I have some idea that might be useful for locally finite groups. However, I realised that except for the definition I know almost nothing about locally finite groups. Is there any place I can find a survey on them for a beginner?

Comment: There is a book by Kegel and Wehrfritz on Locally Finite Groups. That was published in 1973, so will not be up to date, but it is a good place to start. I found it useful, but that was a long time ago. After googling it, I see that there is a Volume 3, published in 2000. Presumably there must be a Volume 2 as well!

Comment: @DerekHolt I have just ordered it. I think the Volume 3 is about the series rather than this particular title, but I'll know when I'll get it.

Comment: @DerekHolt I have recieved the book, it doesn't look like third volum.